# Version-Code field automatically reset to 10000 after creating build

Tags: android, cordova

I have created android web app using cordova 7.0.1 and android platform 6.2.3.Whenever i'm trying to create build using command prompt,it is resetting "version-code" field to 10000 in AndroidManifest.xml file. That is why i'm unable to deploy updated build on GPS.Please help if anyone have idea.TIA

Comment: You have to change `versionCode` on `gradle`

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml ` is generated when you do a command line build. You have to change it somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.Previously I was using "version-code" field in config.xml.But when I modified it with "android:version-code" and changed version code before creating build it worked.